# Jquery ajax return error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using this ajax function

```
function testfunction(ttl){

        jQuery.ajax({url:"",
           type: "POST",
           data: { 'action_sub':'Load_twittercontact'},
           success:function(res){

                  //Do something

         },error:function(e){
                console.log(e.error);

        }});
    }
```

After some time , i got a error in error conolse. This is the error

```
function (){if(!d){var c=arguments,g,h,i,j,k;b&&(k=b,b=0);for(g=0,h=c.length;g<h;g++)i=c[g],j=f.type(i),j==="array"?e.done.apply(e,i):j==="function"&&a.push(i);k&&e.resolveWith(k[0],k[1])}return this}
```

How to solve this issue ?

Comment: please provide the error you are getting, not the source code

Comment: Your error is the source code?

Comment: This is the error which i got in chrome console   function (){if(u){var t=u.length;(function i(t){b.each(t,function(t,n){var r=b.type(n);"function"===r?e.unique&&p.has(n)||u.push(n):n&&n.length&&"string"!==r&&i(n)})})(arguments),n?o=u.length:r&&(s=t,c(r))}return this}

Comment: also this  arguments: null
caller: null
length: 0
name: ""
prototype: Object
__proto__: function Empty() {}
apply: function apply() { [native code] }
arguments: null
bind: function () {
bindAsEventListener: function (object) {
call: function call() { [native code] }
caller: null
constructor: function Function() { [native code] }
length: 0
name: "Empty"
toString: function toString() { [native code] }
__proto__: Object

Comment: check ajax url is working and accepts POST?

Answer (score 1):

Your error handler definition should be like the following code:

> ```
> error: function(requestObject, error, errorThrown) { }
> ```

And to know what exactly happened, you should log the error parameter, like the following code:

> error: function(requestObject, error, errorThrown) {
>
> ```
>      console.log(error);
> ```
>
> }

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks..I tried this and i got this  error: "error"
errorThrown: ""

Comment: I got this error only in Google chrome. In all other browsers it is working fine. Can you help me to solve this issue in Google chrome ?